# how to automatically destroy the frameover time in the stack and go back to previous frame in tkinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I have multiple frames that are invoked through button,the method which I used is stacking method.
now I facing problem in automatically destroying the frame after some time and go back to previous frame.
for example 
in Main.py

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from pageOne import PageOne
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
            '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                                command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                                command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

in pageOne.py

```
from tkinter import *
class PageOne(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                               command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()
```

now I want to close pageOne automatically after sometime and go back to StartPage.

I tried

```
def show_frame(self, page_name):
    if page_name == PageOne:
        page_name.after(5000,PageOne.destroy())
        frame = self.frames[StartPage]
        frame.tkraise()
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()
```

but it did not work

Comment: The code you copied was designed to keep the frames. Just to be clear, you want to _destroy_ the frame? That would prevent you from going to it again. Or are you simply wanting to automatically switch to another frame?

Comment: I want to automatically switch the frame after 5 second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is automatically switch to a different page, you can use `after` to call `show_frame` in the future. There's no reason to destroy a page.

```
def show_frame(self, page_name):
    if page_name == "PageOne":
        self.after(5000, self.show_frame, "StartPage")
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()
```

Comment: Please note that `page_name` in OP is a string, not class reference.  Also it is better to cancel existing `after()` if there is one.

Comment: @acw1668: thanks for pointing that out.  I've fixed the answer.

Comment: as @acw1668 said ,it is a string and i am getting                page_name.after(5000, self.show_frame, "StartPage")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'after'

Comment: Change `page_name.after(...)` to `self.after(...)`.